# Salesforce to Xero integration using Named Credentials by OAuth 2.0

Tags: apex, callout, oauth2, namedcredentials, xero

I am trying to do the integration between Salesforce and Xero by using Named Credentials (Authentication Protocol is OAuth 2.0).
I created an Auth provider -

[image]

Then created Named credentials of OAuth 2.0 type and authenticated with required scopes mentioned in the Xero developer document.

[image]

When I am trying to run the below code to get the Account details from Xero, I am getting "AuthenticationUnsuccessful".

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:XeroDev/api.xro/2.0/Accounts');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

This is the response -

> {"title":"Forbidden","status":403,"detail":"AuthenticationUnsuccessful","instance":"707450d8-b455-47ec-a1b4-85bcb2cf80c9"}

Any suggestion on how to make it work by using Named Credential?

Xero URL - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow

Comment: can you try checking the 'Allow merge fields in HTTP Header' and 'Allow merge fields in HTTP Body'

Comment: Yes tried the same but the response is same.

Comment: Hi, I am facing error after authorizing from xero when it comes back to salesforce it says, We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator. on Ui 

and in URL r?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=invalid_client&ProviderId=0SO2v000000Gvc7

Comment: @Arabinda can you help.

Comment: @Shanker Paudel , can you please send some more details about your SF and Xero connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding xero-tenant-id header in you apex code.
For this you may need to check "Allow merge fields in HTTP Header" or else it wont allow.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:XeroDev/api.xro/2.0/Accounts');
req.setMethod('GET');
/* tenant id is different for different organization */
req.setHeader('xero-tenant-id', 'd5ae8ed7-be06-43c0-a3ee-39e40e4b1eff');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

If you want you can dynamically fetch xero-tenant-id

```
GET https://api.xero.com/connections
Authorization Bearer {{access_token}}
```

response

```
[
    {
        "id": "f192b8df-f13c-4c12-8b01-d3f7590e98fe",
        "tenantId": "d5ae8ed4-be07-43c0-a3ee-31e40e4b1dff",
        "tenantType": "ORGANISATION",
        "createdDateUtc": "2019-12-11T17:08:13.7204600",
        "updatedDateUtc": "2019-12-12T11:19:59.1985240"
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked as expected.

Comment: @TariqueH If the access token expired do we need to manually re-authenticate the name credentials? or do we have any automation process to avoid the authentication fail issue ?

Comment: @Satheesh named credential should take care of refreshing expired tokens. At code level you don't have to worry.

Comment: Hi All -I followed above approach, but I am getting invalid redirect uri error when saving named credentials. 
Can someone please help me ?