# Unauthorized Access using Named Credentials

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, namedcredentials, xero

I am using Named Credentials oAuth2.0 protocol to connect with Xero. I have setup Auth. Provider and Named Credential. Named Credential is also authenticated.

I have followed the steps mentioned here : [Salesforce to Xero integration using Named Credentials by OAuth 2.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287809/salesforce-to-xero-integration-using-named-credentials-by-oauth-2-0)

and https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow

But when i am trying to get Tenant Id using the code below i am getting nothing in response:

```
Http http = new Http();     
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:XeroDev/connections');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {{access_token}}'); // Am i doing it properly??
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug('Body>>'+response.getBody());
```

However if i repeat the same step without using named credentials

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://api.xero.com/connections');
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Cache.Session.get('ACCESSTOKEN'));
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
System.debug('Tenant Body>>'+response.getBody());
```

I am getting Tenant Id. I think there is some syntax issue. Any suggestion?

Beside that, I was trying to make a get callout using hardcoded tenant id to get Account details but i am getting unauthorized access issue.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:XeroDev/api.xro/2.0/Accounts');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('xero-tenant-id', '9c32ea58-ff42-4d30-945e-bc5b54db6f0d');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

> Response =>
>   {"title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"detail":"AuthorizationUnsuccessful","instance":"a17bd5ab-1f77-441c-a688-2cef83c26d95"}

Thanks You!

Comment: try by removing `request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {{access_token}}');` and in named credentials mark the  `Generate Authorization Header` checkbox `true`

Comment: can you give more details or screenshot for your named credential?

Comment: Follow this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287809/salesforce-to-xero-integration-using-named-credentials-by-oauth-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your valuable time & suggestion.

I was able to resolve with help of a few online blogs. Here is the solution :

1. Correct Syntax to use Auth. Parameter from Named credentials :
   **request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');**

   So whole code is this : 

   `Http http = new Http();

   HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
   request.setEndpoint('callout:XeroDev/connections');
   request.setMethod('GET');
   request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
   request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
   HttpResponse response = http.send(request);`
2. I was getting unauthorized access because i have added wrong scope. After correcting it to "openid offline_access profile email accounting.transactions", everything working perfectly fine.